# Prepare http servlet response in the case of socket timeout : Read time out Exception

Tags: java, socket-timeout-exception

In one of my code to get static resources from microservice I have used following code.

```
response = proxyClientStaticResource.execute(getTargetHost(servletRequest), proxyRequest);
```

here `proxyClientStaticResource` is instance of `CloseableHTTPClient`. I have set socket time out for the request using request config:

```
RequestConfig.Builder builder = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setRedirectsEnabled(doHandleRedirects)
                .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.IGNORE_COOKIES)
                .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout)
                .setSocketTimeout(1000);
```

I know that if the request times out it will give socket timeout exception. Whenever I get Socket Timeout exception for that case I need to prepare `HttpServletResponse` for the same. Everything in the response means headers, error code, body everything.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What you return in a response is up to you.  Nobody here can tell you what should be returned.

Comment: Ideally the one who you’re making this code for should tell you what to put in the response of an error.